# Missing Collections in Local Mongo DB in Meteor App

Tags: mongodb, meteor

My Meteor App local mongoDB is missing 2 collections when compared to my live DB on MLab

1. Already double checked my connection string and am connected to same DB.
2. This issue just recently started after pulled a new remote branch but nothing was changed related to the DB.

I don't know what else to try.

What other information can I provide to get a good answer here?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly _missing_ means in this context? Could you show us the code you use to define the collections, and where you are importing/using them? If an error led you to discover your issue, you could post that (and the code you wrote) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what was causing the issue but here's what I did to resolve it.

Dump my live database to a local copy:
mongodump --host ds15XXXX-a0.mlab.com --db   --port 5XXXXX --username  --password

Import to local DB:
mongorestore --drop --host localhost --port 3001 --db meteor ./dump/

Answer (score 2):

Meteor (or its implementation for MongoDB collections, for that matter) does not actually create the collection until there is a reason for it.

Your collection will not be created in the database until:

- a document is inserted into it, or
- an index is created for it.